# Proper way to handle PUT requests Django with forms

Tags: django, forms

I have a web app that allows users to edit previously submitted data.

I'm currently processing PUT requests by manually updating the data.

I would like to use my forms to validate input but I run into the issue of the other required fields.

For instance, if a user updates a date field and I validate it with my form, it errors out as I'm missing other required fields like name, location, etc since the form was designed to be filled out all at once.

What is the best way to use my forms to validate input but conditionally allow required fields if the request is a PUT or POST with model Forms.

Comment: Please post your model code and your form code. Are you using the Django REST framework? Are you using the same ModelForm for adding and updating?

Comment: I was hoping to use the same form, I'm not using DRF, just regular Django

Comment: It is going to be tough to tell you *exactly* what to do without seeing some code... but you should either create an "update" form object/view that only performs the validations you actually want or validate the updated (unsaved) model instance rather than the form.  Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean_fields

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting errors for missing fields you're not using the modelform correctly, sounds like you are not passing it the existing instance to work on.

You need to use a pattern like this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render

def my_view(request, obj_id):
    my_object = get_object_or_404(MyModel, pk=obj_id)
    update_form = MyModelForm(instance=my_object, data=request.PUT or None)
    if update_form.is_valid():
        return HttpResponse(status=204)  # empty success response
    else:
        return render(...)  # render update_form.errors somehow
```

And be sure to include the object id in the url that you send your PUT requests to